# Excel 2013 to Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

How do I Insert, Update and delete Excel file to SharePoint lists. Automatically it has to create columns that are present in Excel sheet & whenever we add a record, update a record or delete a record in Excel sheet it should reflect the same in share point list.

P.S

1. Import data from excel to sharepoint.
2. Insert delete update of record in excel should reflect the same in sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways which I think you can use.

1. First way is to use Import SpreadSheet app provided by the Sharepoint.

http://3sharp.com/blog/load-excel-data-into-a-sharepoint-2013-list-fast-and-easy/

2. If you want to create new list from excel then you can use Export table command

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-list-with-a-Excel-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9

Comment: I want to import excel sheet to share point, and the 2nd you said create new list , im not looking for that, but I want to update sharepoint list from excel.

Comment: So try first one

Comment: for eg, I have imported student database from excel to sharepoint list with 3 columns (Student REG NO, Student Name, Student Course) this should 3 lists in sharepoint, and when I add data it should keep synchronizing in sharepoint list, If id delete record from excel with sync it should also modify the same in SharePoint list. Thanks for your reply, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, this is a real challenge. In the past this was possible, but MS removed that functionality from Excel in version 2010 (?).
If you want to synchronize a sharepoint list outside of SharePoint I would suggest considering MS-Access. That's the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

Import from excel will solve one of your problem. But I really doubt if you modify in excel in real time it will affect? By any chance are you using any server side code? Probably you can write an event receiver in worst case.